# Strategies for deploying geo replicated Microsoft Graph/Office 365 API based application

Tags: office365api, office365-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

We have a web application that uses the Microsoft Graph API and Outlook REST API. We implemented a code authorization flow. This means that its our web server that handles requests to Microsoft Graph and Office 365 APIs.

We are based in Europe (hosted within Azure). Now we would like to replicate our infrastructure overseas to serve a better end-user experience.

What would be the possible strategies regarding these MS APIs.
 Is there a geographical affinity mechanism? Is it based on the geo localization of the requesting app (us) or the localization of the tenant (we have users everywhere)? Staying within Azure Data centers will provide better performance? What would be Microsoft recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked about this, and the answer was that yes, there is an affinity system based on the location of your app. It should hit the instance of Graph or Outlook that's closest to you.

Regarding running in Azure, we are continuously optimizing latencies for Microsoft-owned Azure-based apps & services to access the Graph and Outlook APIs. This work would accrue to all apps and services running in Azure.

Comment: Oh missed your answer. Very interesting tanks !